# C++: `CHttpConnection` & `CInternetSession` OS X / LLVM Clang equivalent?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, mfc

I'm trying to translate some c++ code that was made using Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC) and compiles with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010+ so that it can be executed in Xcode. It's a class that makes a connection to an API, and so it uses the MFC classes `CHttpConnection` and `CInternetSession`. What's the closest equivalent for Mac/Xcode users? If context is needed, see the header file in the "How to connect through the API using C++" section on [this page](https://www.space-track.org/documentation#/howto). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on OSX then you're likely working with ObjC & Foundation. If so then the closest OSX equivalents would likely be [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/), [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/), and [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/) (as far as I know the api is the same for iOS and OSX). If you're not dealing with ObjC on OSX and/or you really need a C++ implementation of those MFC types, then you'll probably have to roll them yourself using sockets.

(Actually, there's nothing that prevents you from using [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) or [libwget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) - the C libs behind a couple of the examples from your link. At the very least they might save you some time.)